# ftp fails before prompting for password input

Tags: ftp

When connecting by ftp to example.com, it fails before prompting for password for a longer string:

```
user@client:~> ftp example.com
Connected to example.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 17:56. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (client:username): ftpusername@example.com
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection.
ftp: Login failed.
```

But if I try to login with a smaller string:

```
user@client:~> ftp example.com
Connected to example.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 17:58. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (client:username): f@example.com
331 User f@example.com OK. Password required
Password:
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: HTTP 421 means [Misdirected Request.](https://httpstatuses.com/421) It looks like your server is not configured to accept logins from `ftpusername`.

Comment: But this is a FTP connection, not a HTTP one.

Comment: While you are right that @Ultrasonic54321 is totally wrong with the reference to HTTP, the root cause is probably the same. Do you have any reason to believe you should be able to login with `ftpusername@example.com`? Can you login with that account using any FTP client whatsoever?

Comment: Well, I don’t know. But if I type a short string like bebe@example.com, or vzxw@example.com, or whatever, it prompts me for the password. It looks like the username string should be smaller

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking us what your username should be like?

Comment: The thing is, it’s not my username. Partner supplied me the credentials and I should send him the files. But as you can see, I can’t connect, because it’s not prompting for password with that long username. But if I type anything else shorter for username, it’s prompting me for password. I don’t understand if the problem is at me, the client, or at him, the server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot solve the problem on your side.

Comment: So I've connected as a client from a different machine and it seems that I can login, the input password is prompting me for entry. For sure there's something wrong with my client.

Comment: What client did you use on the different machine?

Comment: the same FTP built in by Linux. The only difference is that second machine is Ubuntu, while the first one is SUSE.

Comment: You should still contact the server administrator. It would be way easier to solve with his/hers help.